Extend the topic to "Software Security"?
I am feeling really good in the RE website, the topics feet me and the discussions are quite interesting. But, then I noticed the IT-security website and tried to see what kind of community was there (I read a lot and ask a few questions to test the community).
It appears that the do not simply care about software security (i.e. advanced buffer-overflow exploitation, heap-based exploitation, string-format bugs, Java bytecode exploits, ... and so on).
So, my question is: Reverse-engineering is already quite interesting, but could we extend our interest also to any deep and technical problems linked to software exploitation (i.e. software security which include both obfuscation/deobfuscation and deep understanding of software to exploit it) ?
As an example, the question Understanding the most recent heap implementation under Linux has been marked 3 times for closing because it is out of scope for reverse-engineering... But, try to ask such a question in IT-security and you will wait forever for an answer (not the good community to ask). So ?
EDIT: Note that I do not suggest to change the name (Reveser-Engineering) of the website. But, to extend a bit the scope of it (accept questions about software security in a wider manner). I started creating a tag software-security. This should be enough.

There are plenty of questions about exploits on [security.se], they aren't going unanswered more than other kinds, and some experts do hang out there, so I wonder where you get your impression that “the [sic] do not simply [sic] care about software security”. Software security is the main focus of [security.se].

I think I had this feeling because it appear to me that most of the questions (and, thus, the answers) are more focused on giving recipes to strengthen the security of a computer system and not understanding how it works and discover the potential vulnerabilities. I admit that I may have misinterpreted what I saw. But, somehow, I think it is a natural way to have the IT-security website to be concerned about finding solutions to problems and RE website to be concerned about finding answers to questions. Even if they are dealing with the same topic.

I noticed this as well and suggested an exploit development stack. This got shotdown, fast.
